# Calling a method in a UIViewController from a UIButton in a subview

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, uibutton, protocols

Still learning about Objective C and getting the structure right.

I have an iOS App with a UIViewController that has a defined method named "doSomething". In my view controller I have a view and in that view a number of UIButton that I create programmatically (see example below with one button).

[image]

Now when I press the button I want to call my method "doSomething". The way I currently do it is like this:

```
[myButton addTarget:nil 
             action:@selector(doSomething:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Since my target is nil it goes up the responder chain until it finds a method called "doSomething". It works, but it does not really feel right.

I have started to look into using @protocol but not really got my head around it. I have been looking at some tutorials but for me it is not clear enough. I have used protocols like  for the table view controllers, but defining one is new for me.

Would it be possible to get an example for this specific case?

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't this feel right? It's what the responder chain was build for, and it's exactly the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your target pass in the view controller and the method will be called on that object.

Edit:

```
[myButton addTarget:controller 
             action:@selector(doSomething:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Assuming that you have a variable called controller that is your UIViewController. If you don't have a reference to your controller then simply pass one to your view.

Edit2:

View interface:

```
@property (assign) UIViewController* controller;
```

View implementation:

```
@synthesize controller;
```

Controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    someView.controller = self;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit skorulis. Now we are getting close, but I guess I'm still not good enough for doing that. I guess it is so natural for you, but I don't know how to reference back to my UIViewController, which I guess is the core here...

Comment: Thanks for edit 2! Now we are complete ;-) I have tested and it works like clockwork and I have learned something new today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is set the value of `addTarget` to `self`.

```
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(doSomething:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

This will look for the method `doSomething` on the object that the target is added in. In this case, this would be the view controller.

Comment: Thanks cs. I tried that before and I think it will go to the UIView, not the UIViewController. If I change to self I get an "unrecognized selector sent to instance". That's why I changed it to nil.

Comment: Can you post your code so I have a better idea of what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Hi cs, I think skorulis is on the right track, just that I'm not smart enough yet to know the actual code...