# UIButton target to be UIViewController not custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` which creates a custom sub view. The sub view is a `UIView` object which has been subclassed a few times.

Within the subview class I create a custom init method:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Init code
        [self spm_correctGuessViewCustomInit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And within this I create a button and a label. The question relates directly to the button and its target action.

What I would like is for the `UIViewController` to have the buttons action, not the subclasses `UIView` (which actually creates and holds the button).

```
[continueButton addTarget:self.superview action:@selector(correctGuessContinueButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I pass in the target of self.superview, this appears to work correctly and the correct method is run. However, I am shown a warning in the subclass 'Undeclared selector 'correctGuessContinueButtonPressed''

So am I implementing this approach correctly? Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to update your custom view's `init` method so it takes `target` and `action` parameters (much like the `addTarget:` method of the button). You could then pass these values to the button via the `addTarget:` call.

```
- (instancetype)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    // your normal init code here
    // use target and action to setup your button
}
```

Comment: It seems strange I would have to pass that information down to the init method. If I simplify this some more lets say I have a UIViewController with its standard view. I then subclass a UIView and add that to the view controllers view. In the creation of the UIView subclass I also add a button to this subclassed view. I would like the button to call a selector (method) on the view controller, not on itself. Is that simple/possible?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. The view controller calls this new `initWithTarget:action:` method pass `self` as the target and some selector for the action. This way the custom view has no direct knowledge of the view controller.

Comment: So self would be the view controller that is requesting its creation which would then be the target, right?

Comment: Right, I understand I will accept your answer as the answer and add my own too for reference. I also was able to find a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119071/calling-a-method-in-a-uiviewcontroller-from-a-uibutton-in-a-subview - I needed to add a reference to the controller as a property and ensure the method that was called by the button was in the controller header file as previously it was only in the imp file which could have caused the issue too

Comment: what if you have multiple buttons with different target actions on the custom uiview and want the viewcontroller with an object of that custom uiview to handle those multiple target actions instead of the custom uiview?

Answer (score 0):

Your view.superview approach will not bring you to the view controller, but to a view.

You can import the header of your implementing class to fix the warning, but I think your design should be improved. Views should work pretty much on their own and not depend on their superviews, or even worse the whole architecture of views and controllers.

I'd pass a delegate down the line that gets called when the user pressed the button, or set some blocks on the views that get called when buttons fire.

Avoid communication over several layers of abstraction.

Comment: Right, you are correct the superview would actually link to the controllers view however the correct method still appears to be called. I think this seems like a lot of work for a simple task, using delegates in this example. All I have is a UIViewController and a UIView. Lets keep it that simple for now. I would like the custom uiview added to the view controllers view, to have a button. The button in the subclasses uiview should call the selector (method) on the uiviewcontroller. Is that a simple task?

Comment: It isn't a simple task, if you have to think about its implementation. :) I really would connect the target/action of the button to its immediate container, either view or controller - the one who initiates it. You can even put dirty "climb-the-hierarchy"-code in there. Trying to set some "superview" or containing view controller directly as the target is not easy - it requires the view to be added already as a subview, before the instantiation in complete... Another approach for "decoupled communication": NSNotificationCenter. Don't abuse that, though.

Comment: Thanks, I did another search and found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119071/calling-a-method-in-a-uiviewcontroller-from-a-uibutton-in-a-subview - which appears to be what I am after, simply creating a reference to the controller and also ensuring the method was in the controller header file to be seen by compiler appears to have done the trick. That's as simple as its going to get I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Reference previous similar question: [Calling a method in a UIViewController from a UIButton in a subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119071/calling-a-method-in-a-uiviewcontroller-from-a-uibutton-in-a-subview)

1. I had to add an import to the View Controller that the method was on, within the custom `UIView` subclass.
2. With the controller property set I could set the button target as controller
3. Ensure that the method that was being called from the button was in the controller header file, so could be seen by the subview implementation file. Previously this was not so the subview was not to know this existed.